# PHP detecting java applet's completion

Tags: java, php, applet

Currently my PHP script has the following structure:

```
<?PHP bla bla bla some code ?>

<applet> my java applet here </applet>

<?PHP bla bla some code (part 2) ?>
```

The problem is that part 2 starts after applet launching, but I need to wait until it finishes, so is there any good solution to fix this?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, Applet runs on the client ... so this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something wrong with async loading of applet and other... it seems to be inpossible.. but try this

-- warning: this code is not tested!

```
<?PHP bla bla bla some code ?>

<div id="applet-container"></div>

<?PHP bla bla some code (part 2) ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("applet-container").innerHTML = "<applet> my java applet here </applet>";
</script>
```

so you will insert it later into the container it allows you to not block the page loading.. or read abou async loading of applets